# Замена вывода в php

Tags: php

Доброе время суток, есть скрипт который обращается к mysql базе и делает вывод в html таблицу. 
Пример вывода из базы: SIP/120-00000001 
Нужна php функция которая бы переименовала SIP/120-ХХХХХХХХ в имя.

Имя например Василий у SIP/120-ХХХХХХХХ, а у SIP/130-ХХХХХХХХ Геннадий.
Вот код.

```
    <?php

function db_connect() {
    if (!mysql_connect($GLOBALS["db_host"], $GLOBALS["db_user"], $GLOBALS["db_pwd"]))
        die("Can't connect to database");
    if (!mysql_select_db($GLOBALS["database"]))
        die("Can't select database");
}

db_connect();

$zapros="";
if ($_GET["oa"]=="on")
$zapros="disposition=\"ANSWERED\"";
if ($_GET["from"]){
    if ($zapros=="")
    $zapros=$zapros . " src like \"%$_GET[from]%\"";
    else
    $zapros=$zapros . " and src like \"%$_GET[from]%\"";
}
if ($_GET["to"]){
    if ($zapros=="")
    $zapros=$zapros . " dst like \"%$_GET[to]%\"";
    else
    $zapros=$zapros . " and dst like \"%$_GET[to]%\"";
}

if ($_GET["to"]){
    if ($zapros=="")
    $zapros=$zapros . " dst like \"%$_GET[to]%\"";
    else
    $zapros=$zapros . " and channel like \"%$_GET[to]%\"";
}

if ($_GET["to"]){
    if ($zapros=="")
    $zapros=$zapros . " dst like \"%$_GET[to]%\"";
    else
    $zapros=$zapros . " and dstchannel like \"%$_GET[to]%\"";
}

if ($_GET["cd"]=="on")
if ($_GET["date_from"]){
    if ($zapros=="")
    $zapros=$zapros . " calldate BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$_GET[date_from] 00:00:00','%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AND STR_TO_DATE('$_GET[date_to] 23:59:59','%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s')";

    else
    $zapros=$zapros . " and calldate BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$_GET[date_from] 00:00:00','%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AND STR_TO_DATE('$_GET[date_to] 23:59:59','%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s')";
}

if($zapros==""){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
}
else {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table} where $zapros ORDER BY calldate");
}
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
echo "<tr><td><b>Время звонка</b></td><td><b>На какой номер</b></td><td><b>Откуда</b></td><td><b>Куда</b></td><td><b>Переведён</b></td><td><b>Запись разговора</b></td><td><b>Время разговора</b></td></tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$t= date( 'd.m, H:i', convdate("$row[calldate]"));
$d=$row["disposition"];
if ($row["disposition"]== "ANSWERED") {
    $d="<a href=# onClick=window.open(\"play.php?id=$row[uniqueid]\",\"\",\"width=390,height=200\");>$row[disposition]</a>";
}
echo "<tr><td>$t</td><td>$row[channel]</td><td>$row[src]</td><td>$row[dst]</td><td>$row[dstchannel]</td><td>$d</td><td>$row[billsec] / Сек</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table></body></html>";
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Comment: как то так возможно?

Answer (score 2):

в какое имя? Как вариант - создать массив типа `$arr = array('key'=>'value');` где key - ваше значение из БД, value - имя которое надо получить по ключу. Получате вывод из бд в переменную $var. тогда имя можно вычислить так:

```
 if (isset($arr[$var])){
      $name=$arr[$var];
 } else {
      $name = false;
 }
```